# JavaFX: ProgressIndicator TableCell implementation query

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, progress-indicator

First post @SO, here it goes. I've searched extensively for this, but failing to arrive at a proper solution, I had to proceed with this question.

I have just recently started learning JavaFX/Java and I am trying to build a table which, along with some other columns, would have a single ProgressIndicator column. This means that a ProgressIndicator needs to be displayed within a table cell.

Work I've done so far: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QxSmsJCT

```
    @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    fileName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("fileName"));
    transferSpeed.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, Double>("transferSpeed"));

    piColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, Double>("piColumn"));
    ProgressIndicatorTableCell pitc = new ProgressIndicatorTableCell();
    piColumn.setCellFactory(pitc.<TableCell>forTableColumn());

    transferTable.setItems(data);
}

class ProgressIndicatorTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, Double> {
    public <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, Double>, TableCell<S, Double>> forTableColumn() {
        return new Callback<TableColumn<S, Double>, TableCell<S, Double>>() {
          @Override
          public TableCell<S, Double> call(TableColumn<S, Double> param) {
            return new ProgressIndicatorTableCell<>();
          }
        };
    }
}
```

While the other columns work perfectly (and display the data I feed them), I'm not able to figure out why the ProgressIndicator doesn't show up at all.

I request SO's considerate answerers to please try to explain your answer(s) with a bit of detail, so that I could understand the concept clearly, instead of just "getting" the answer. If the errors and mistakes within my code's logic and/or project hierarchy setup could be highlighted, it would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should include the basic code needed to reproduce the problem inside of your post as well as Pastebin.  That way, if ever Pastebin closes in the future, your question will still make sense. Pro tip: use Ctrl+Shift+K to indent your code with 4 spaces and have StackOverflow format it for you.

Comment: Do you need a `ProgressIndicator` rather than a `ProgressBar`? There is already a [`ProgressBarTableCell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ProgressBarTableCell.html) class, if that works for you. Your `ProgressIndicatorTableCell` implementation doesn't implement anything to do with rendering the cell, which is why it is blank (e.g. there is no `ProgressIndicator`).  The [`ProgressBarTableCell` source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/298ec4ec6b35/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/cell/ProgressBarTableCell.java) might help.

Comment: Yes, I need a ProgressIndicator, specifically. I tried the code you linked me to, and after appropriate modification of it (for use with ProgressIndicator), it is now displayed. However, no matter what I set the progress value to, it is always in "indeterminate" mode. I tried using setProgress as follows: http://pastebin.com/e3NbnSW2 within my previously linked code.